# Why it's impossible to use freq=_freq_alert as an argument in a library function

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

in my library I have a function with the string *freq* alert as argument but I get this error

```
export freq_alert(string _txt, string _freq_alert) =>
    alert(_txt, _freq_alert)
```

Cannot call 'alert' with argument 'freq'='_freq_alert'. An argument of 'series string' type was used but a 'input string' is expected.

And I call my function like this

```
freq_alert = alert == 'LIVE' ? alert.freq_once_per_bar : alert.freq_once_per_bar_close

f.freq_alert('test', freq_alert) =>
```

Do you know a way of using a 2-choice alert in a library ?

Comment: freq_alert parameter accepts input string, i.e. its value cannot be changed in the runtime of the script and must be constant (frequency of the alert cannot change at the time alert script is running)

Comment: Ok thanks, and there's no solution?

Comment: no, you can't use it in library

Comment: you may still use it in indicator, see answer

Answer (score 0):

freq_alert parameter accepts input string, i.e. its value cannot be changed in the runtime of the script and must be constant (frequency of the alert cannot change at the time alert script is running)  https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Type_system.html#qualifiers

you can't use it in library
you may still use it in indicator

```
//@version=5
library("MyLibrary")

alTypeInput = input.bool(true, "Live alert") 
freqtype = alTypeInput ? alert.freq_all : alert.freq_once_per_bar_close

if barstate.isrealtime
    alert("text", freqtype)
```

Comment: I did it... it's too obvious 




`export test(string _opt_alert) =>
    if _opt_alert == 'LIVE'
        alert('text 1', alert.freq_once_per_bar)
    else
        alert('text 2', alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)`